# On hover of the menu sub-menu shows and the content slide down. How not to slide the content down and sub-menu overlap on content?

Tags: html, css

on hover of the main menu sub-menu appears and the content after the main menu slides down. here it the code snippet

html:

```
<div id="holderDiv">
   <div id="menu">
      <a href="#" id="items">Menu 1</a>
   </div>   
   <div id="submenu" style="height:100px;background:green;">
      <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
      <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
      <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div style="height:500px;background:red;text-align:center">Content</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#submenu").hide();

$("#menu").on('mouseover', function () {
     $("#submenu").slideDown(500);
});

$("#holderDiv").on('mouseleave', function () {
       $("#submenu").slideUp(500);
});
```

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YKKrM/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YKKrM/2/)

Code i've added:

```
#submenu {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help, add position absolute to #subDiv, then  #subDiv overlap the content Div.

```
#submenu{

position:absolute;
    width:90%;
padding:20px 20px  0 20px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YKKrM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/YKKrM/5/

I added `style="position: relative;"` to your holderDiv, and `position: absolute; width: 100%;` to the submenu style.

Here's the updated html:

```
<div id="holderDiv" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" id="items">Menu 1</a>
    </div>
   <div id="submenu" style="height:100px;background:green;position: absolute; width: 100%">
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
<div style="height:500px;background:red;text-align:center">Content</div>
```

Tip: I'd suggest that you use css classes instead of inline style.